# Creating a new equation and plotting it

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

Simulating the Solow model. Let the saving rate be 20%, and the depreciation rate be 10%. The production function is Cobb-Douglas with α=1/3.
. The population starts at 1, and its growth rate is n=0.02.

a. Simulate a Solow economy for 40 years. This means that you will need to calculate capital, labor and GDP for every year using the model equations learned in class. Start with a low level of capital of k[0] = 0.05. Plot the path of GDP. This means that you plot the value of GDP from year 0 to 39. Also plot the path of GDP per person.

b. Same as part a, but in period 20, suppose the country's saving rate increases from 20% to 30%. Plot the paths of GDP and GDP per person.

I have part a but I cannot figure out b.

```
import numpy as np 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 

def F(A,K,L):
    return A*K**α*L**(1-α)
α=1/3
A = 1 
K0 = 0.05
L0 = 1
x = np.arange(40)

K = K0*1.1**x
L = L0*1.02**x

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(x, F(A,K,L),'b-', linewidth=2, label='GDP')
ax.plot(x,F(A,K,L)/L,'r-', linewidth=2, label='GDP per person')
ax.legend(loc='upper left')
ax.set_title('Solow Growth GDP')
plt.show()
```

this gave me the right answer for part a. I cannot figure out what to do to get part b correct. Everything I try does not keep the line graph as one continuous line but it breaks it up at that 20th period when the function changes.

Comment: This question as written cannot easily be answered, as @123 correctly notes below. First, please [see here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions) regarding homework questions. Second, please consider [reviewing this page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) describing how to ask a good question.

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to help you with this, but it is quite hard to grasp what you are trying to achieve. The following questions came to my mind:

- Do you want to just plot b in a new window?
- Plot it in the same window?
- Solving the problem which variables you have to change to get the right result?

If you want to solve the math problem, the question should be asked on math.stackexchange.com.

I assume now you want to know which variables you have to change.
Please try for:

```
K = K0*1.2**x

x = np.arange(20)
```

Note: I find it to be easier to work with the linspace function and not arange. You can look it up at https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.linspace.html#numpy.linspace

**Deeper explanation why I changed the listed variables:**
x are your points you are putting into the function. It is quite common that x is the time(x is therefore often called "t"). "np.arange(40)" pointed to the 40years. Thats why I'm assuming np.arange(20) should be right.
With this K = K0*1.1**x points to exponential growth. The factor 1.1 is your "growth factor". You have a saving rate of 20% and a depreciation rate of 10% therefore getting a end saving rate of 10% or differently written 1.1. If your saving rate rises from 20% to 30% you get a end saving rate of 20%, or 1.2 -> K = K0*1.2**x.
My gut feeling tells me that your teacher is probably heading to Differential Equations. They are quite hard to understand in the beginning but super cool if you understand them.